# WorkFlow Based in a Field - AppMaker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm new with JavaScript and Google App Maker and I have a doubt with a little Workflow to Approve Expense.

I have two models:

1. Requests (Details of Request input by Widget)

```
| RequestedBy | TypeOfExpense | WhoApprove | WhoResponsableToExecute | Approved | Executed |
```

2. TypeOfExpense (Inputed by Admin via Widget)

```
| Type | ApproverOfExpense | RensableToExecute |
```

***Scenario***: A user creates a request choosing  type of expense >> According Type >> Approver are notified - After approved >> RespnsableToExeute are notified - Affter Execution >> User is notified.

What feature I can use to associate (or trigger) in *Request* with `ApproverOfExpense` (from `TypeOfExpense`) and `RensableToExecute` (from `TypeOfExpense`) when an user input the Requisition of expense.

I'm think using `onCreate` events in Data Source but the app can are very slow.

Comment: Have you take a look at Document Approval template? - https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/document-approval/

Comment: Thanks by reply  @PavelShkleinik !
Yes I see this template
But in our  Worlflow the requestor don't know who is approver and executer (Is the my doubt). 
The approver and executer are defined by TypeOfExpense

Comment: Just to clarify my doubt .. I need create a type of trigger to associate two or moore fields  between two Database according on load a field by user

Answer (score 0):

I think onCreate is the right approach. It shouldn't make things noticeably slower as all it has to do is look up a single association, which is pretty fast. So basically what it sounds like you need to do is:

In the onCreate for request:

```
var email = record.TypeOfExpense.ApproverOfExpense;
// Email the approver.
```

And then maybe in OnSave for the request:

```
if (oldRecord.Approved === false && record.Approved === true) {
  var email = record.TypeOfExpense.RensableToExecute;
  // Email person who needs to execute
}
```